# Open source API for uploading videos to youtube from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, youtube

I found that I can use either:

1. YouTube API
   Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library
2. List item

Are there any options (eg. open source APIs) which I can use to do video uploading to youtube?

Comment: YouTube API Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library is already good enough. What is your point of finding alternatives?

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C. So I just want to find something that makes the learning curve as gentle as possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need tutorials more than an alternative of library.

Here are some found from the Internet:

- http://everburning.com/news/mytube-from-the-ground-up/
- http://everburning.com/news/mytube-installing-the-image-wall/
- http://everburning.com/news/mytube-now-with-moving-images/